# Which type of iterable/list in Python is able to structurally share the same items from previous iterables/lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, collections, referential-integrity

Say I have two long lists `a` and `b` and want a list `c`:

```
a = [obj1, obj2, ..., objN]
b = [objNplus1, objNplus2, ..., objNplusM]
c = a + b
```

How can I create a new list that shares the previous ones as its start and end, but without violating the referential integrity of any of them, i.e. without changing `a` nor `b`; and, also without recreating the entire list `c` from start?
Is there something similar to such a list as part of the default collections or as part of an external package?

I suppose it is something like a tree, perhaps with an associated linked-list mimicking a DFS.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

> Make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the iterables are exhausted. Used for treating consecutive sequences as a single sequence.

For example:

```
import itertools
c = itertools.chain(a, b)
```

Update: To more closely emulate a `list` you can write your own class, for example:

```
class ListOfLists():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._lists = args
        self._len = sum(map(len, self._lists))

    def __iter__(self):
        for _list in self._lists:
            for item in _list:
                yield item

    def __getitem__(self, y):
        if y >= self._len:
            raise IndexError
        for l in self._lists:
            if y > len(l):
                y -= len(l)
            else:
                return l[y]

    def __len__(self):
        return self._len

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ["a", "b", "c"]
c = ListOfLists(a, b)

print("Total length is", len(c))
print("4th element is", c[4])
for i, item in enumerate(c):
    print(i, ":", item)
```

output:

```
Total length is 6
4th element is b
0 : 1
1 : 2
2 : 3
3 : a
4 : b
5 : c
```

You should probably implement other methods (such as `__getslice__()` if you need slicing) as well. Also it is not recursive, meaning that you can only merge "regular" `list`s in its existing form. It won't work if you pass `ListOfList`s to the constructor.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Perhaps. Although the last paragraph (_"something like a tree, perhaps with an associated linked-list mimicking a DFS"_) implies that the OP is aware that it requires a different data structure than a list.

Comment: @Selcuk `chain` has the exact behavior I need, except by the fact it is consumable, and when converted to list it is recreated from scratch. The closest I could get was nesting the lists: `[[0,1,2], [3,4,5]]` and traverse it recursively. The more lists appended, the deeper it gets. A disadvantage is that this is not directly subscriptable.

Comment: @viyps You can write a custom class then. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Selcuk impressive answer!